# How much variance is there in the execution time for individual Java Bytecodes?

Tags: java, performance, profiling, bytecode, instrumentation

Ideally a measure of cpu cycles per bytecode would show this, although I haven't been able to find much on the topic.

Edit:
If I have a program which can be optimized in two different ways, and each optimization results in 5 less bytecodes executed for each variant program, both optimizations cannot be told apart from this measure.

However, the 5 bytecodes in each may translate into radically different performance characteristics when run on a JVM as measured in time (assuming the JVM can made behave as similar as possible when measuring both programs).

How many bytecodes would the two optimized variant programs need to differ by, before you could be reasonably sure that one is better performing than the other?

Comment: Quite a bit I would expect. Additionally, I would expect it varies by platform, version and architecture. Java is clearly not a RTOS, so what does knowing this help you do?

Comment: I am interested in how bytecode count could be used as a proxy measure for program performance, given that profiling Java in a stable way is difficult. How much error can bytecode count expect to contain?

Comment: You don't, you can't and you need to read about the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) before you go too much further.

Comment: I'm using [bycounter](https://sdqweb.ipd.kit.edu/wiki/ByCounter) I'm already much further on than you'd like on this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arbitrarily large.

Even if you consider only a single VM implementation running on a single processor, there is huge variation due to the use of Just In Time Compilation. The VM doesn't necessary execute the bytecode operations one by one. Instead, it analyzes it, optimizes them, and compiles it to native code. So there is not necessarily any correspondence between the bytecode and execution time.

Comment: Would the variance be less arbitrary if you could stabilize the JVM environment and restrict it to only interpreting code?

Comment: @McOda Yes, but then you will measure a different thing: the interpretation speed of a JVM, something which isn't that useful, and does not give any insights on actual interpretation.

Comment: I am interested in the comparison of the measures. If the measures of interpreting two bytecodes are the same (both take the same time to interpret), I take it they may be wildly different than some measure of whatever these two different bytecodes get compiled down to?

Comment: That is, I'm interested in the comparison of the measures as a ratio. I'm not interested in the absolute measures. Though the ratio of the measures of two bytecodes would probably change a lot depending on whether the measures were taken during interpretation or execution?

Comment: Interpertation time tells you nothing about how long it would take under compilation.

Answer (score 0):

This makes no sense. The execution of any bytecode takes quite some time... nobody really should care about. The time-critical code gets compiled into native instructions and then there's no correspondence with the bytecode allowing you to say how long a `iload_1` takes.

Multiple bytecodes get often compiled into a single HW instruction, some bytecodes may get compiled into multiple HW instruction, but quite often, it's hard to tell what happens (e.g. instead of 3 bytecodes you have 5 HW instructions).

Then we come to the problem of timing of HW instructions, which is maybe even more complicated:

- multiple (typically 4) instructions can execute in parallel
- due to data dependencies, some instructions may be blocked
- they get executed [out of order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out-of-order_execution)
- and so on....

Comment: One minor quibble, there isn't *no correspondence with the bytecode at all* it's more that a one-way transform occurs and then the bytecode is no longer consulted. Clearly the native code corresponds to the bytecode (if only because they're equivalent).